# Python Azure Function not correctly running when importing a class/module

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am trying to run an Azure Function in Python
and need to import a class from a module. It appears that the function is only running the class, but not the rest of the program. The class logs in to a website, converts a csv to a dataframe, and returns the dataframe. I have researched the folder structure and it appears that I am doing all steps correctly. The module is in a folder called shared_code and function is in another folder called Intelie_Alerts (I have tried to absolute import and relative import).Any help on how to get this function to run appropriately. I was expecting to import the module, run the class, then clean the dataframe and send to database.The function is not failing, but I am not getting anything sent to the database.

[image]
[image]

```
import azure.functions as func
from shared_code.Intelie_Creds import Intelie


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:

    intel = Intelie()
    byte_stream = intel.csv_custom()





File Structure:
 <project_root>/
 | - .venv/
 | - .vscode/
 | - Intelie_Alerts/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - shared_code/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - Intelie_Creds.py
 | | - function.json
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, this is working as expected. Since the function isn't failing, one of the reasons you are receiving is might be due to the trigger that you are using. By default, the cron expression for a timer trigger would be `0 */5 * * * *` which takes time to trigger the function. The above cron expression triggers a single time per day at minute 5 of each hour. I would suggest you to change the cron expression and check for the same.

For demonstration purposes, I have replaced Timer Trigger with HTTP trigger and check for the same and got the expected results. Below is the function that I'm using.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from shared_code.Intelie_Creds import Intelie

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    intel = Intelie()
    print(intel)
    return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Comment: Intelie is a Class in the module and csv_custom() is a method in the class. I am still unable to have the function perform the task of transforming the csv after calling Intelie